# Higher-Level design tools for databases

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I need to design a database schema for a set of data and I watched a Coursera video where the professor talks about "Higher-Level Design Tools" but doesn't say any example.
I'm putting a link for my screenshot below so you can understand what I am talking about. My question is: how do theses tools work? Are there good examples?

http://oi60.tinypic.com/34qjpd3.jpg

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Currently, there is no auto-magical software tool that will produce your database design.  There are many fancy GUI tools that make it easier than using a text editor to generate DDL statements.  However, you will need to create the schema.

Comment: Thank you @gjsduarte. SQL Server looks interesting.

Comment: Thank you @KM. And yes, I think I will continue studying design concepts to create my schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the professor is talking about design tools such as Sybase PowerDesigner.

These tools allow you to design databases in different levels of abstraction from high level (Conceptual Data Model) to low level (Physical data model), they also provide tools for generating diagrams and even the final code depending on your database type.

Comment: Awesome. I just saw some videos about Sybase. I think I can use it in my project. Thank you very much